# Elementary Sorts Running Time Comparisons

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time

I've been learning about elementary sorts in class recently (bubble sort, insertion sort, and selection sort) and have been a bit confused with the running times.

On a homework that the teacher has given us, a question asks:
"Which of the 3 elementary sorts run the fastest for a file with all keys identical? What about for a file with data in reverse order?"

For the first part of the question, I'm not entirely sure what they mean by "keys". So, does it mean that there is an array of size 1 with multiple data? I don't think "keys" are the same as "data". I know that if all of the data were ordered, then insertion sort would be the fastest but I'm not sure if that would have any affect on the problem.

For the second part of the question, I'm thinking that it would be selection sort since that would take a constant number of comparisons no matter the number of inversions in the data. Insertion sort and bubble sort would result in too many exchanges.

I'm mostly just confused on the first part of the question.

Comment: You're on the right track. Which algo is fastest when everything in the set being sorted is identical `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', ..]`, i.e. no swaps. Which algo is fastest when set is in reverse order, ie. many swaps.

Comment: So insertion sort for first one, and selection for second one?

Comment: I think you're correct that insertion sort would be good when there are few swaps, that is, when the set is mostly sorted already. You're also right that selection sort may be better when there are a substantial number of swaps. But neither of these algos will out perform mergesort unless you're working with small datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in my experience, when sorting a file, one can say the file consists of "records" and you are moving each record so that it appears prior to all the records it should be prior to. The "key" is whatever part of the record you are using in order to determine whether one record should be before or after another record.  If you are just sorting numbers or strings, then the "key" is the entire record.  In other cases each record might be someone's school transcript, and for some reason you want to sort these records by the student's name, so most of the data in the record is not part of the key.  It would be helpful if your teacher has said what he or she considers to be the unit of data that is moved during a swap.

I think you are thinking correctly about the case where the records are already sorted, and all keys identical is one such case.

For the case where the records are in exactly reverse order, the question isn't so much how much the number of comparisons in selection sort are affected by the initial order of the data; rather, the question (regarding comparisons) is whether any of the algorithms will be able to perform fewer than the others.  Usually we say insertion sort takes fewer comparisons than selection, but in this case you may be able to show otherwise.  And of course you also need to look at how many comparisons bubble sort will actually need.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher question is:

**Which of the 3 elementary sorts run the fastest for a file with all keys identical ?**

In other word, the question is:

**Which of the 3 elementary sorts have the minimum Time Complexity for the Best Case ?**

**Time Complexity:** an asymptotic mathematical notation that represent the rate of growth of running time in relation to input size.

**Best Case:** The list is already sorted, this includes the case of identical entries.

What are the 3 elementary Sorts ?

- **Insertion sort** with `O(n)` on Best Case.
- **Selection sort** with `O(n^2)` on Best Case.
- **Bucket Sort** with `O(n+k)` on Best Case.

So the best elementary sorting algorithm on the best case is **Insertion sort** with `O(n)`.